# How to call the GeoJSON dynamically according to area selection in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson

I'm trying to get GeoJSON according to the selection of a particular area. For example, if I have selected a built up area it will only show that area . I'm calling GeoJSON data through a PHP page, and I have created the plunker for this ([this is the example](https://plnkr.co/edit/y21BMZ4Z2PANLVAyuw7k?p=preview)).

The main problem I'm having is how to assign the vector value from another page to show the GeoJSON.

See this is my JavaScript page where I'm trying to assign the data:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $.getJSON("php/drpdwn.php", success = function(data){
            var items="";
            for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
                items +="<option value='"+data[i].id+"'>" + data[i].name+"</option>";
            }
            $("#a1_title").append(items); 
            $("#a1_title").change();
        });
        $("#a1_title").change(function(){
      var selectedValue = $(this).find(":selected").text();
   if( selectedValue == "Landuse/landcover") {

              $.getJSON("php/lulc_db.php",success = function(data){              
                  var items="";
                  for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
                      items+="<option value='"+data[i]+"'>" + data[i] +"</option>";
                  }
                  var myNode = document.getElementById("a2_title");
                  while (myNode.firstChild) {
                      myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
                  }
                  // ADD NEW ITEMS
                  $("#a2_title").append(items);  
              });
              $("#a2_title").change(function(){
    $("#save").on('click',function(){   
        $.ajax('php/geojson.php?layer=Built Up').then(function(response) {

  var geojsonFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
  var features = geojsonFormat.readFeatures(response,
      {featureProjection: 'EPSG:4326'});
  vector.setSource(features);
}); 
    });
});
          }
```

And this is the way I'm adding vector layer:

```
         var vectorSourcec = new ol.source.Vector({
              format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
              });
    var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
          source:vectorSourcec

          });
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          }), vector],
  renderer: 'canvas',
target: document.getElementById('map'),

            view: new ol.View({
            Projection: 'EPSG:4326',
                center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([79.17436, 21.01668]),
  zoom: 5
                                }),
        });
```

Please improve me here where I'm doing.

Comment: You said " I'm calling geojson data through php page ", how is that? i don't see it.

Comment: @ShahzadBacha not in the plunker ..i'm getting that result in my project ..In plunker ..calling it through json there is multipolygon.json file...just for information i write here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your geojson back use the `ol.format.GeoJSON()` to parse the object and create the features.

```
var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
var myGeoJsonObj = ....asign the geojson result here
var myGeoJsonFeatures = format.readFeatures(myGeoJsonObj )
```

and then you may place your features in a vector layer using. 
    `vecLayer.getSource().addFeatures(myGeoJsonFeatures);`

@Shahzad Bacha is correct. No call to get geojson within your plunker

**UPDATE**
check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/0zsopzw1/) to see your data in action

Comment: Please check the pluncker again in `script.js` file  i'm calling multipolygon.json

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/y21BMZ4Z2PANLVAyuw7k?p=preview check this i have tried your way it doesn't work .I'm getting an error  `vectorSources.getSource is not a function`

Comment: there are several errors within your plunker. Your get request is never called. Check the network within the firebug cosnole, no request is executed

Comment: I have updated my answer to provide you a fiddle using your geojson data.

Comment: Please the question ...i'm able to call directly on page ` var vectorSourcec = new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
   Projection: 'EPSG:4326'
   url : 'php/geojson.php?layer=Built Up'
   });` but i'm not able to call dynamically ..please correct me on my code

Comment: and i can't call data on the same page ..because need to add 5-6 layer of geojson data so thats why i need filter out ...and i'm  badly stuck on this problem please help me.. if you can

Comment: did you check my fiddle? It is working fine using your own data.Your map epsg code is 3857. unless you provide a different one.

Comment: no worries amigo. glad to help